# How to subscribe to updates of a specific package?

Tags: package-management, repository

I'd like to recieve some sort of notification when a new version of [nss-pam-ldapd](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/nss-pam-ldapd) package is available on the archive.ubuntu.com repository.

Is there an email list or any other tool of this sort I can subscribe to?

Comment: No, there is no current mechanism or tool to notify you of *specific* package changes/updates in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup special software on your machine or in your browser.

- Use [SiteDelta Watch](https://sitedelta.schierla.de/index.en.php) addon in Firefox. It scans page or its region for changes and show notification if interesting area of page was changed. You need to do the following:

  1. install this addon from [addons.mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sitedelta-watch/)
  2. open needed page https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/nss-pam-ldapd in Firefox
  3. click SiteDelta Watch button on Firefox toolbar and click *Monitor*

     [image: monitor changes]
  4. Then click on down arrow to open right sidebar

     [image: open sidebar]
  5. Click *Add new* and select paragraph with version number

     [image: select region]
  6. That is all, SiteDelta Watch will inform you on page change.
- Other method is to set up local python watcher - [`urlwatch`](https://github.com/thp/urlwatch):

  1. Install it

     ```
     sudo apt install python3-pip python3-keyring
     pip3 install urlwatch --user
     pip3 uninstall keyring
     ```
  2. Set it up according to [recommendations from official GitHub page](https://github.com/thp/urlwatch) - create file `~/.config/urlwatch/urls.yaml` with contents:

     ```
     name: "APT package watch"
     url: "https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/nss-pam-ldapd"
     filter:
       - xpath: '//*[@id="content"]/h1'
       - html2text: re
     ```

     Note: in code above `xpath: '//*[@id="content"]/h1'` refers to the `h1` header element with text *Source Package: nss-pam-ldapd (0.9.9-1) [universe]* (as in SiteDelta method).
  3. Run `urlwatch` first time manually and create [`crontab` job](https://github.com/thp/urlwatch#quick-start) for it. [SMTP notifying](https://github.com/thp/urlwatch#e-mail-via-gmail-smtp) is supported too.

Personally I use both - SiteDelta and URLWatch.

Comment: I just tried out urlwatch and i realy like how to set it up. But it fails at a lot of realy popular sites pages because its detected as a bot. I am testing out sitedelta now. I hope it works better. Do you have any other suggestions for 2020?

Comment: I'm using SiteDelta without issues.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/vooruit/events/?ref=page_internal shows up empty if i want to configure it