# Software (ubuntu), aggregator/feed reader, bookmark based

Tags: customization, client, bookmarks, web-feed

everyone, hello!

is there a software (not an online service)

- allowing to enter/save any urls (of news websites, twitter/telegram accounts, etc.),
- updating every X timeframe (hour or day) to check if new stuff has been published on this links
- so that I can have, all in one place, offline, on ubuntu, all my bookmarks, without having to check them individually everytime to see if something new happened

what key words to use to search for that? customizable news aggregator unubntu feed reader.

thank you!
glad

Comment: There are some browser addons like SiteDelta for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sitedelta-watch/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) and/or [Chromium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sitedelta-watch/bkpoemflpiempcejpkoifiaklcjfkbak?hl=en-US). See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1119959/66509) for details.